# Which event or function is triggered when Tree node is expanded/colapsed ( Flex 4.5 )

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, tree, treenode

Hello
I am looking for the function or event, which is called when tree node is expanded/colapsed inside Tree object in Flex 4.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the The [itemOpen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html#event:itemOpen) event or the [itemOpening](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html#event:itemOpening) Event.